# Iterations In From Loop

Tags: vba, iteration

is there a way to say in vba something like:

```
from x = 1 to 100, by 10
```

so that the x's are 1, 10, 20, 30, etc. to 100?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **STEP**:

```
for x = 0 to 100 step 10

next x
```

This will take you through `0, 10, 20... 100`

Since you want to start at `1` and go `1, 10, 20... 100`, here is a slight modification

```
for x = 0 to 100 step 10
    if x = 0 then 
        y = 1 
    else
        y = x
    end if

    '// use y in all calculations downstream instead of x

next x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For y = 0 To 10
    If y = 0 Then x = 1 Else x = 10 * y

    ' do stuff with x

Next y
```